# React nested Accordion Parent not updating height

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, tailwind-css

I am trying to build the mobile version of my homepage, My nested accordion "Projects" seems to have a bug where it doesn't show the correct height of the bottom projects section on the first open.

To open that, you first click on the projects text, then it lists out the projects and then you click on the project toggle the Project Card.

[image: Screenshot of visual bug]

(Updated) I believe this is happening because my parent Accordion is not re-updating its height when the child Accordion opens.

Do you know a good way of doing this? Or if needed should I restructure my components in a way that makes this possible? The difficulty is the fact that Accordion accepts children, and I reuse Accordion inside it so it's rather confusing. I know I can potentially use a callback function to trigger the parent but not quite sure how to approach this.

Homepage.tsx

```js
import { Accordion } from "@/components/atoms/Accordion"
import { AccordionGroup } from "@/components/atoms/AccordionGroup"
import { AccordionSlideOut } from "@/components/atoms/AccordionSlideOut"
import { Blog } from "@/components/compositions/Blog"
import { Contact } from "@/components/compositions/Contact"
import { Portfolio } from "@/components/compositions/Portfolio"
import { PuyanWei } from "@/components/compositions/PuyanWei"
import { Resumé } from "@/components/compositions/Resumé"
import { Socials } from "@/components/compositions/Socials"
import { Component } from "@/shared/types"

interface HomepageProps extends Component {}

export function Homepage({ className = "", testId = "homepage" }: HomepageProps) {
  return (
    <main className={`grid grid-cols-12 pt-24 ${className}`} data-testid={testId}>
      <section className="col-span-10 col-start-2">
        <AccordionGroup>
          <Accordion title="Puyan Wei">
            <PuyanWei />
          </Accordion>
          <Accordion className="lg:hidden" title="Portfolio">
            <Portfolio />
          </Accordion>
          <AccordionSlideOut className="hidden lg:flex" title="Portfolio">
            <Portfolio />
          </AccordionSlideOut>
          <Accordion title="Resumé">
            <Resumé />
          </Accordion>
          <Accordion title="Contact">
            <Contact />
          </Accordion>
          <Accordion title="Blog">
            <Blog />
          </Accordion>
          <Accordion title="Socials">
            <Socials />
          </Accordion>
        </AccordionGroup>
      </section>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Portfolio.tsx

```js
import { Accordion } from "@/components/atoms/Accordion"
import { AccordionGroup } from "@/components/atoms/AccordionGroup"
import { ProjectCard } from "@/components/molecules/ProjectCard"
import { projects } from "@/shared/consts"
import { Component } from "@/shared/types"

interface PortfolioProps extends Component {}

export function Portfolio({ className = "", testId = "portfolio" }: PortfolioProps) {
  return (
    <AccordionGroup className={`overflow-hidden ${className}`} testId={testId}>
      {projects.map((project, index) => (
        <Accordion title={project.title} key={`${index}-${project}`} headingSize="h2">
          <ProjectCard project={project} />
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </AccordionGroup>
  )
}
```

AccordionGroup.tsx -
The purpose of AccordionGroup is to only allow one child Accordion to be open at one time. If an Accordion is not in AccordionGroup it can open and close independently.

```js
"use client"

import React, { Children, ReactElement, cloneElement, isValidElement, useState } from "react"
import { AccordionProps } from "@/components/atoms/Accordion"
import { Component } from "@/shared/types"

interface AccordionGroupProps extends Component {
  children: ReactElement<AccordionProps>[]
}

export function AccordionGroup({
  children,
  className = "",
  testId = "accordion-group",
}: AccordionGroupProps) {
  const [activeAccordion, setActiveAccordion] = useState<number | null>(null)

  function handleAccordionToggle(index: number) {
    setActiveAccordion((prevIndex) => (prevIndex === index ? null : index))
  }

  return (
    <div className={className} data-testid={testId}>
      {Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
        isValidElement(child)
          ? cloneElement(child, {
              onClick: () => handleAccordionToggle(index),
              isActive: activeAccordion === index,
              children: child.props.children,
              title: child.props.title,
            })
          : child
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Accordion.tsx

```js
"use client"
import { Component } from "@/shared/types"
import React, { MutableRefObject, ReactNode, RefObject, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Heading } from "@/components/atoms/Heading"

export interface AccordionProps extends Component {
  title: string
  children: ReactNode
  isActive?: boolean
  onClick?: () => void
  headingSize?: "h1" | "h2"
}

export function Accordion({
  className = "",
  title,
  children,
  isActive,
  onClick,
  headingSize = "h1",
  testId = "Accordion",
}: AccordionProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState("0px")
  const contentHeight = useRef(null) as MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isActive === undefined) return
    isActive ? setHeight(`${contentHeight.current?.scrollHeight}px`) : setHeight("0px")
  }, [isActive])

  function handleToggle() {
    if (!contentHeight?.current) return
    setIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState)
    setHeight(isOpen ? "0px" : `${contentHeight.current.scrollHeight}px`)
    if (onClick) onClick()
  }
  return (
    <div className={`w-full text-lg font-medium text-left focus:outline-none ${className}`}>
      <button onClick={handleToggle} data-testid={testId}>
        <Heading
          className="flex items-center justify-between"
          color={isActive ? "text-blue-200" : "text-white"}
          level={headingSize}
        >
          {title}
        </Heading>
      </button>
      <div
        className={`overflow-hidden transition-max-height duration-250 ease-in-out`}
        ref={contentHeight as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}
        style={{ maxHeight: height }}
      >
        <div className="pt-2 pb-4">{children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

ProjectCard.tsx

```js
import Image from "next/image"
import { Card } from "@/components/atoms/Card"
import { Children, Component, Project } from "@/shared/types"
import { Subheading } from "@/components/atoms/Subheading"
import { Tag } from "@/components/atoms/Tag"
import { Text } from "@/components/atoms/Text"

interface ProjectCardProps extends Component {
  project: Project
}

export function ProjectCard({
  className = "",
  testId = "project-card",
  project,
}: ProjectCardProps) {
  const {
    title,
    description,
    coverImage: { src, alt, height, width },
    tags,
  } = project
  return (
    <Card className={`flex min-h-[300px] ${className}`} data-testid={testId}>
      <div className="w-1/2">
        <CoverImage className="relative w-full h-full mb-4 -mx-6-mt-6">
          <Image
            className="absolute inset-0 object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-l-md"
            src={src}
            alt={alt}
            width={parseInt(width)}
            height={parseInt(height)}
            loading="eager"
          />
        </CoverImage>
      </div>
      <div className="w-1/2 p-4 px-8 text-left">
        <Subheading className="text-3xl font-bold" color="text-black">
          {title}
        </Subheading>
        <Tags className="flex flex-wrap pb-2">
          {tags.map((tag, index) => (
            <Tag className="mt-2 mr-2" key={`${index}-${tag}`} text={tag} />
          ))}
        </Tags>
        <Text color="text-black" className="text-sm">
          {description}
        </Text>
      </div>
    </Card>
  )
}

function CoverImage({ children, className }: Children) {
  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>
}
function Tags({ children, className }: Children) {
  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, t is a bit challenging with this implementation here, because when you want to update the height of the grandparent Accordion from its child one, you can't really know from there, which corresponding grandparent Accordion you want to update unless you pass props to the grandparent Accordion and also pass props to the in-between component (`Portfolio` for example, i.e child Accordion's parent) so it can propagate them to its child Accordion.
 by doing that, we can make the grandparent and child Accordions communicate somehow.
 Maybe this is not the best solution you can find, but sadly, I cannot think of a better one.

---

So to recap: the idea is to create a state in the top level to hold heights that refer to each parent Accordion, so it is an array where the length is set "manually" which makes it somehow ugly, but if you have to use an array of data to display your components dynamically, then it is not a problem we will discover that later, also we will see the limitation of the workaround.

---

### Workaround:

Now we'll go with the simplest and most straightforward fix that works for what is included in the question.

As mentioned, first we create the state in the HomePage component:

```js
const [heights, setHeights] = useState(Array(7).fill("0px")); // you have 7 parent Accordions
```

After creating the array state at the top level, Now, to each Accordion component, we pass the state setter function `setHeights`, the index `indexx`, and also the corresponding height `heightParent` if it is a parent Accordion

```js
<AccordionGroup>
  <Accordion title="Puyan Wei" heightParent={heights[0]} setHeights={setHeights} indexx="0">
      <PuyanWei setHeights={setHeights} indexx="0" />
  </Accordion>
  <Accordion title="Portfolio" heightParent={heights[1]} setHeights={setHeights} indexx="1">
      <Portfolio setHeights={setHeights} indexx="1" />
  </Accordion>
  //...
  <Accordion title="Socials" heightParent={heights[6]} setHeights={setHeights} indexx="6">
      <Socials setHeights={setHeights} indexx="6" />
  </Accordion> 
</AccordionGroup>
```

**Note:** `indexx` props passed to parent and `indexx` props passed to the in-between component (Portfolio) **they should have the same value** indicating the corresponding index, this is in fact, the key of the solution.
it is named 'indexx' with two 'x' to avoid conflict later.

Then, From the in-between component you pass those received props to the child Accordion:

```js
export function Portfolio({
  className = "",
  testId = "portfolio",
  indexx,
  setHeight,
}: PortfolioProps) {
  // update props interface
  return (
    <AccordionGroup className={`overflow-hidden ${className}`} testId={testId}>
      {projects.map((project, index) => (
        <Accordion
          title={project.title}
          key={`${index}-${project}`}
          headingSize="h2"
          indexx={indexx}
          setHeight={setHeight}
        >
          <ProjectCard project={project} />
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </AccordionGroup>
  );
}
```

Now from your child Accordion component, you are able to update the height of the corresponding Accordion parent in the HomePage state, getting advantage of the passed `indexx` props, so when we update the child height we also update the parent height

```js
function handleToggle() {
  if (!contentHeight?.current) return;
  setIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  let newHeight = isOpen ? "0px" : `${contentHeight.current.scrollHeight}px`;
  if (!heightParent) { // there is no need to update the state when it is a parent Accordion
    setHeight(newHeight);
  }
  setHeights((prev) =>
    prev.map((h, index) => (index == indexx ? newHeight : h))
  );
}
```

Finally, when you specify the height for one Accordion you can check if it receives `heightParent` as props so we know it is a parent one, by this, we let the Accordion component uses `heightParent` as `maxHeight` and not its own state `height` if it is a parent one, that's the reason behind ignoring updating the `height` state when it is a parent Accordion that get opened, therefore, we have to change the way `maxHeight` property is set, now it should depend on the nature of the Accordion:

```js
style={{ maxHeight: `${heightParent? heightParent : height }` }}
```

---

If you want to make the parent Accordion just uses its state `height` as `maxHeight` and just keep your code as it is so it makes more sense

```js
style={{ maxHeight: height }}
```

you can still do this, by adding a `useEffect` in the Accordion component and making sure its runs only when the received `heightParent` props is updated and also defined, we do that to be sure the code there is only running when it is a parent accordion that should update its `height` state:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
 if(heightParent){
   setHeight(heightParent)
 }
},[heightParent])
```

As said, this makes more sense and it is most beautiful too, but I still prefer the first one since it is more straightforward and also **saves one additional render**.

---

### Working with data dynamically:

If we have data stored in an array and we want to display our components based on that we do this instead:

```js
const data = [...]
const [heights, setHeights] = useState(data.map(_ => "0px")); 
//...
<section className="col-span-10 col-start-2">
 <AccordionGroup>
  {data.map(element, index => {
     <Accordion key={index} title={element.title} heightParent={heights[index]} setHeights={setHeights} indexx={index} >
       {element.for === "portfolio" ? <Portfolio setHeights={setHeights} indexx={index} /> : <PuyanWei setHeights={setHeights} indexx={index} /> }  // just an example
     </Accordion>
  })
  }
 </AccordionGroup>
</section>
```

You can notice here we have to specify a `key` in the parent accordion so we can use it instead of `indexx` but you know the `key` property is special and we don't want to mess with it anyways, hope you get the idea

---

### Limitation:

It is obvious this solution works only one level, so if the child Accordion gets itself a child Accordion, then you have to wrap your head around it again, but likely if I understood what you are doing, you will not face that, since with your implementation the child Accordion is supposed to show items, but who knows maybe one day you'll need to make it return another child Accordion, and that's why I consider my suggestion a workaround rather than an optimal solution.

---

Like I said, it might not be the best fix, but honestly, especially with this implementation, **I don't think** such a multi-level working solution exists, please prove me wrong, I'm following the post.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem analysis:

TL;DR: The parent accordion needs to be aware of these changes, so it can adjust its own height accordingly.

I suppose you might be using [`amiut/accordionify`](https://github.com/amiut/accordionify), as illustrated by "**[Create Lightweight React Accordions](https://dev.to/amiut/create-lightweight-react-accordions-4dej)**" from [Amin A. Rezapour](https://dev.to/amiut).
It is the only one I find using `AccordionGroup`.

The nested accordion structure in your app involves parent-child relationships where the child accordion's height changes dynamically based on whether it is expanded or collapsed.

That is illustrated by your `Portfolio.tsx`, where the `AccordionGroup` component contains multiple `Accordion` components that are created based on the `projects` array. These `Accordion` components are the "child" accordions mentioned:

```js
export function Portfolio({ className = "", testId = "portfolio" }: PortfolioProps) {
  return (
    <AccordionGroup className={`overflow-hidden ${className}`} testId={testId}>
      {projects.map((project, index) => (
        <Accordion title={project.title} key={`${index}-${project}`} headingSize="h2">
          <ProjectCard project={project} />
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </AccordionGroup>
  )
}
```

Each child `Accordion` contains a `ProjectCard` that displays the project details. When a user clicks on an `Accordion` (or "project"), it expands to show the `ProjectCard`.
That is where the height change comes into play; the accordion will expand or collapse based on user interaction, changing its height dynamically.

The dynamic height is managed in `Accordion.tsx`:

```js
  function handleToggle() {
    if (!contentHeight?.current) return
    setIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState)
    setHeight(isOpen ? "0px" : `${contentHeight.current.scrollHeight}px`)
    if (onClick) onClick()
  }
```

When the `handleToggle` function is called, it checks whether the accordion is currently open (`isOpen`). If it is, the height is set to "0px" (i.e., the accordion is collapsed). If it is not open, the height is set to the scroll height of the content (i.e., the accordion is expanded).

The dynamic height change of these child accordions is the key part of the issue you are experiencing. The parent accordion needs to be aware of these changes, so it can adjust its own height accordingly.

I see in the same `Accordion.tsx`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isActive === undefined) return
    isActive ? setHeight(`${contentHeight.current?.scrollHeight}px`) : setHeight("0px")
  }, [isActive])
```

The height of the accordion is set based on the `isActive` prop, which represents whether the accordion is currently open or not. If it is open, the height is set to the scroll height of the accordion content (effectively expanding the accordion), and if it is not active, the height is set to `0px` (collapsing the accordion).

However, while this effect correctly adjusts the height of each accordion based on its own `isActive` state, it does not account for changes in the heights of child accordions.

When a nested (child) accordion changes its height (due to being expanded or collapsed), the height of the parent accordion is *not* recalculated and therefore does not adjust to accommodate the new height of the child.

In other words, the parent accordion is not aware that it needs to re-render and adjust its height when the height of a child accordion changes. That lack of re-rendering when the nested accordion expands or collapses leads to the issue of the parent accordion not showing the correct height.

### Possible solution

TL;DR: The solution would involve making the parent aware of the height changes in the child accordion so that it can adjust its own height accordingly.

(one of the techniques mentioned in "**[React: Force Component to Re-Render | 4 Simple Ways](https://josipmisko.com/posts/react-force-rerender)**", from [Josip Miskovic](https://josipmisko.com/))

Your `Accordion` component could benefit from a callback function prop that gets invoked when its height changes, for example `onHeightChange`. Then, in your `Portfolio` component, you could propagate this height change upwards to the `Homepage` component by passing a new callback function to the `Accordion` component that utilizes the `onHeightChange` prop.

`Accordion.tsx`:

```js
export interface AccordionProps extends Component {
  title: string
  children: ReactNode
  isActive?: boolean
  onClick?: () => void
  onHeightChange?: () => void
  headingSize?: "h1" | "h2"
}

export function Accordion({
  className = "",
  title,
  children,
  isActive,
  onClick,
  onHeightChange,
  headingSize = "h1",
  testId = "Accordion",
}: AccordionProps) {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isActive === undefined) return
    isActive ? setHeight(`${contentHeight.current?.scrollHeight}px`) : setHeight("0px")
    if(onHeightChange) onHeightChange() // Call the onHeightChange callback
  }, [isActive])

  // ...
}
```

And then modify your Portfolio component to propagate the height change event:

```js
export function Portfolio({ className = "", testId = "portfolio", onHeightChange }: PortfolioProps & {onHeightChange?: () => void}) {
  return (
    <AccordionGroup className={`overflow-hidden ${className}`} testId={testId}>
      {projects.map((project, index) => (
        <Accordion 
          title={project.title} 
          key={`${index}-${project}`} 
          headingSize="h2"
          onHeightChange={onHeightChange} // Propagate the height change event
        >
          <ProjectCard project={project} />
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </AccordionGroup>
  )
}
```

Finally, you can add a key to your Portfolio accordion on the Homepage that will change when the height change event is triggered. That will cause the accordion to re-render:

```js
export function Homepage({ className = "", testId = "homepage" }: HomepageProps) {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(Math.random());
  //...

  return (
    //...
    <Accordion className="lg:hidden" title="Portfolio" key={key}>
      <Portfolio onHeightChange={() => setKey(Math.random())} />
    </Accordion>
    //...
  )
}
```

That way, you are forcing a re-render of the parent Accordion component whenever a child Accordion's height changes.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the link to that post on how to force rerendering! I'm not actually using amiut/accordionify, these are just my own components that I wrote, I guess the structure looks very similar, what a coincidence!